# Is there any grammar mistake in the sentence?

Tags: grammar

**Researchers hypothesize that sharks sometimes confuse humans for another type of animals they usually consume, different from seals or fish.**

Is there a grammar mistake in the above sentence? I think another should be replaced by other, is that right?

Comment: Proofreading is off-topic, but I don't think _other_ is right. I would suggest using _the animals they usually consume_ (sharks can only eat species that they find in the sea!).

Comment: Should be "with **other** type**s** of animals".  If using singular, then keep that all the way through: "another type of animal".    The last part "different from..." is confusing. The humans are different from seals, or the other types of animals are different from seals, or the sharks are different from seals?  Maybe add another sentence or reword it.